# Aframe animation component not removing

Tags: aframe

I have attempted a few ways to remove the animation (from the html attribute itself):

```
element.components["animation__0"].remove(); 
//above works, but has no affect on html list, just "stops" animation.  

delete element.components.animation__0;
//works, in theory but html attribute still there
```

> $("#id").removeAttr("animation__0"); //results in the error below:

```
aframe-animation-component.js:468 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of null(…)
getUnit @   aframe-animation-component.js:468
getValidValue   @   aframe-animation-component.js:523
getTweenValues  @   aframe-animation-component.js:584
(anonymous function)    @   aframe-animation-component.js:601
(anonymous function)    @   aframe-animation-component.js:594
getTweensProps  @   aframe-animation-component.js:592
getTweens   @   aframe-animation-component.js:614
createAnimation @   aframe-animation-component.js:755
animation   @   aframe-animation-component.js:784
update  @   aframe-animation-component.js:128
updateProperties    @   component.js:211
value   @   a-entity.js:446
value   @   a-entity.js:607
attr    @   jquery.js?hash=22a0055…:8028
removeAttr  @   jquery.js?hash=22a0055…:8068
(anonymous function)    @   jquery.js?hash=22a0055…:7991
each    @   jquery.js?hash=22a0055…:442
each    @   jquery.js?hash=22a0055…:194
removeAttr  @   jquery.js?hash=22a0055…:7990
(anonymous function)    @   VM8102:1
```

I have also tried to flushToDOM() after deleting components etc... Didn't seem to change any html

Code Pen: http://codepen.io/msj121/pen/yVVmvL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this fork of your pen:
http://codepen.io/thoragio/pen/xRgKBQ

I replaced `cylinder.components["animation__scale"].remove();` with `cylinder.removeAttribute("animation__scale");` and the DOM is now being updated.

Also, the first `console.log()` needs to be outside of the `setTimeout()` method or else you are just calling them both at the same time.

Comment: Sadly, as stated in the question flushToDOM didn't work. I will post some more code.

Comment: Looks like the Jquery version was an issue causing the error. But nice to be reminded of a non-Jquery approach since updating Jquery doesn't seem easy in the framework, thanks.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.